# Definition of custom `@@hasInstance` method in Javascript

Tags: javascript

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/hasInstance#custom_instanceof_behavior) suggests to define a `@@hasInstance` method either using `class` and `static` keywords or using `Object.defineProperty()` as follows:

```js
function Foo() {}
Object.defineProperty(Foo, Symbol.hasInstance, {
  value(instance) {
    return false
  },
});
```

**How comes that following definition doesn't work for creating a `@@hasIntance` method?**

```js
function Foo() {}
Foo[Symbol.hasInstance] = function(instance) { return false }
```

It even fails to create the property.

```js
console.dir(Foo) // it doesn't show the Foo[Symbol.hasInstance] property
Foo[Symbol.hasInstance] === Function.prototype[Symbol.hasInstance] // evaluates to true
Object.hasOwn(Foo, Symbol.hasInstance) // evaluates to false
```

However when different symbol is used, the property is created as expected:

```js
function Foo() {}
Foo[Symbol.iterator] = function(instance) { return false }
console.dir(Foo) // it shows the Foo[Symbol.iterator] property
Object.hasOwn(Foo, Symbol.iterator) // evaluates to true
```

Tested on Firefox 113 and Chrome 114.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because `Foo` is a function, and by default, all functions inherit from `Function.prototype` object which has a read-only `Symbol.hasInstance` property on it:

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Function.prototype, Symbol.hasInstance));
/*
{
  "value": function [Symbol.hasInstance]() { [native code] },
  "writable": false, <-- important
  "enumerable": false,
  "configurable": false
}
*/
```

You cannot create shadowed properties via assignment if the property already exists in the prototype chain and is read-only:

```js
const myPrototype = Object.create(null, {
  x: {
    value: 1,
    writeable: false
  }
});

const obj = Object.create(myPrototype); // obj [[Prototype]] ---> myPrototype

obj.x = 2; // attempt to add an own property for 'x' on `obj` with a value of 2. This doesn't work as `x` is defined on obj's [[Prototype]] which is read-only.
console.log(obj.x); // still 1
```

As you can see, the above displays `1` still, as `x` on the prototype of `obj` is read-only (`writeable: false`). The same applies for your case. The prototype object of `Foo` has its own `Symbol.hasInstance` property which is read-only, so you can't add an own-property to the `Foo` object directly. In strict mode, your code will also throw an error indicating this issue:

```js
"use strict";
function Foo() {}
Foo[Symbol.hasInstance] = function(instance) { return false } // attempt to create an own property

// "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property...
```

When defining an own-property with `Object.defineProperty`, it doesn't look up at the prototype properties like assignment `=` does, instead, it looks at the object passed into the method to decide if it's ok to add the new property. Your example with `Symbol.iterator` works as it's not defined on `Foo` or `Function.prototype` (the object that `Foo` inherits from), so there is no read-only conflict like there is with `Symbol.hasInstance`.

Comment: In addition, to understand the motivation behind this behavior, see this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38215392/8926512

Comment: @DennisKats Thanks for that, helps me remember this stuff when there's some context behind the behavior :)