Why is it not possible to define a [Symbol.hasInstance] static method using simple property assignment?
There are two code snippets to show the problem I got.
demo1.js:
// using ES6+ class syntax

class MyObject {
  constructor() {
    this.myProp1 = 'myProp1';
  }

  get [Symbol.toStringTag]() {
    console.log('[Custom Symbol.toStringTag]]');
    return 'CustomTag';
  }

  static [Symbol.hasInstance](instance) {
    console.log('[Custom Symbol.hasInstance]');
    return false;
  }
}

const myObj = new MyObject();

console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(myObj));  // works correctly, implicitly called custom getter Symbol.toStringTag
// first log print [Custom Symbol.toStringTag]], then log print [object CustomTag], since custom getter Symbol.toStringTag return 'CustomTag'

console.log(myObj instanceof MyObject);  // works correctly, implicitly called custom static method Symbol.hasInstance
// first log print [Custom Symbol.hasInstance], then log print false, since custom static method Symbol.hasInstance return false

demo2.js:
// using classic prototype syntax

function MyObject() {
  this.myProp1 = 'myProp1';
}

Object.defineProperty(MyObject.prototype, Symbol.toStringTag, {
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  get() {
    console.log('[Custom Symbol.toStringTag]]');
    return 'CustomTag';
  }
})

// is this a correct way to define a static method to MyObject by using classic prototype syntax?
MyObject[Symbol.hasInstance] = function (instance) {
  console.log('[Custom Symbol.hasInstance]');
  return false;
}

const myObj = new MyObject();

console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(myObj));  // works correctly, implicitly called custom getter Symbol.toStringTag
// first log print [Custom Symbol.toStringTag]], then log print [object CustomTag], since custom getter Symbol.toStringTag return 'CustomTag'

console.log(myObj instanceof MyObject);  // does not works correctly, does not implicitly called custom static method Symbol.hasInstance
// just log print true

My Question:

in demo1.js, everything works fine as expected.
in demo2.js, does MyObject[Symbol.hasInstance] = function (instance) { ... } is a correct way to define a static method by using classic prototype syntax?
in demo2.js, if MyObject[Symbol.hasInstance] = function (instance) { ... } is correct way to define a static method, why the js operator instanceof does not implicitly call custom static method Symbol.hasInstance?

btw, about the well-know Symbol Symbol.hasInstance, pls refer to MDN web page

I don't know about using Symbol... with CtorFunc.prototype syntax, but usually it isn't necessary to use defineProperty to define a "static" method member, you'd ust go MyObject.myStaticMember = function() { /* do stuff */ } - but this all predates the introduction of Symbol - so it's unusual to mix the two, imo.

I can't answer your questions ("why ..."), but the example shows how you can get your expected result: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/hasInstance#custom_instanceof_behavior You should also use Object.defineProperty for hasInstance: Object.defineProperty(MyArray, Symbol.hasInstance, {. Here is a working code: https://jsfiddle.net/tk74zuya/

@Dai in demo2.js, Im not using defineProperty to define a "static" method member, I just using defineProperty to define a "getter", since I can not declare a "getter" without using ES6+ class syntax or defineProperty

@Lucas Yes you can - use the get modifier.

@jabaa do you mean Object.defineProperty(MyObject, Symbol.hasInstance, { ... })?

Yes, I copied and pasted the line from MDN, but I fixed it in the JSFiddle.

@Dai I guess I got ur point, do you mean MyObject.prototype = { get [Symbol.toStringTag] { ... } }? but in demo2.js, Im using MyObject.prototype.xxx = xxx; syntax.

It looks like Object.defineProperty does something that MyObject[Symbol.hasInstance] = ... doesn't and that is required for the instanceof operator. The answer to 2. is yes, that's one correct way to define a static method, but it's not the only way and it's not enough to make instanceof work as expected.

Your question is related to Trying to understand the official ES6 spec regarding Symbol.hasInstance and answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38215027/trying-to-understand-the-official-es6-spec-regarding-symbol-hasinstance/38215392#38215392. I'm not sure if I would call this a duplicate (especially after I wrote an answer )

@jabaa Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/29602584/1048572 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/35177663/1048572?

@Bergi All three questions would be valid dupe targets if the OP knew that this specific method is frozen/not writable. I first had to do some evaluation and read different MDN pages to find the actual reason and the other questions.

The problem in your code is that you can't overwrite the Symbol.hasInstance of a function with a simple assignment.
That is a special case:

Unlike most methods, the Function.prototype[Symbol.hasInstance]() property is non-configurable and non-writable. This is a security feature to prevent the underlying target function of a bound function from being obtainable. See this Stack Overflow answer for an example.

MDN Function.prototype[Symbol.hasInstance]() Description
Here is some evaluation:


function f(v) {
  return v === 3;
}

const A = {
  [Symbol.hasInstance]: f
}

console.log("2 instanceof A:", 2 instanceof A); // false
console.log("3 instanceof A:", 3 instanceof A); // true
console.log("A[Symbol.hasInstance] === f:", A[Symbol.hasInstance] === f); // true

const B = {};

B[Symbol.hasInstance] = f;

console.log("2 instanceof B:", 2 instanceof B); // false
console.log("3 instanceof B:", 3 instanceof B); // true
console.log("B[Symbol.hasInstance] === f:", B[Symbol.hasInstance] === f); // true

function C() {}

C[Symbol.hasInstance] = f;
C.otherMethod = f;

console.log("2 instanceof C:", 2 instanceof C); // false
console.log("3 instanceof C:", 3 instanceof C); // false
console.log("C.otherMethod(3):", C.otherMethod(3)); // true
console.log("C[Symbol.hasInstance] === f:", C[Symbol.hasInstance] === f); // false
console.log("C.otherMethod === f:", C.otherMethod === f); // true



To overwrite the method, you can use Object.defineProperty:


function f(v) {
  return v === 3;
}

function D() {}

Object.defineProperty(D, Symbol.hasInstance, { value: f});

console.log("2 instanceof D:", 2 instanceof D); // false
console.log("3 instanceof D:", 3 instanceof D); // true
console.log("D[Symbol.hasInstance] === f:", D[Symbol.hasInstance] === f); // true




thank you for mentioning the MDN Description
